C# How to log in with HTTP POST protocol first and then show the homepage with "WebView" package?
How to log in with HTTP POST protocol first and then show the homepage with "WebView" package?
The website needs to log in with HTTP POST protocol first, and then the web will be directed to its homepage.
The code shows me logging in successfully, but when calling "Browser.Source=url", the web still shows the log-in page to me.
How to share the login result to the WebView so that the web will show the homepage directly.
WebviewPage.xaml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="ProjTest.WebviewPage">
    <StackLayout>
        <WebView x:Name="Browser" WidthRequest="1000" HeightRequest="1000" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>

WebviewPage.xaml.cs
namespace ProjTest
{
    public partial class WebviewPage : ContentPage
    {
        public WebviewPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        async protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            bool Is_Pass = await Login_Post(email, password);
            if (Is_Pass == true)
            {
                string url = "https://TestABC.com/home.php";
                Browser.Source = url;
            }
        }

        async public Task<bool> Login_Post(string email, string password)
        {
            try
            {
                var formContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
                {
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("email", email),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", password),
                });

                var myHttpClient = new HttpClient()
                {
                    Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)
                };
                var response = await myHttpClient.PostAsync("https://TestABC.com", formContent);

                var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
#if Debug_Message
                await DisplayAlert("Login_Post Exception", ex.ToString(), "ok");
#endif
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}

